# Flash card application

Tags: android

I'm developing a flash card application for the Android platform.  So far I have a rough skeleton of a functional application but have hit a road block.

The application works like this:

Once the top button `Flash Cards` is Selected the application starts a new activity:

The user is then able to add a new deck by clicking the add the deck button.  Once a deck has been created the idea is that the user will be able to add cards into the corresponding subject.

This is where I am stuck.  I need to know what the best practice is for creating a list that only corresponds to the given subject.  For example, biology flash cards go under the biology deck, chemistry flash cards under the chemistry deck, etc.

Here is my code for the deck list activity.  My thoughts so far have included somehow bundling a 2D ArrayList into a new activity that created the flash cards.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**LISTOFDECKSACTIVITY:**

```
 public class ListOfDecksActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ListView listView1;
    private Button addDeck;
    final static int deckData = 0;
    private ArrayList<Deck> deck_data;
    private DeckAdapter adapter;
    private View header;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deck_list);

        instantiate();

    }

    private void instantiate() {
        deck_data = new ArrayList<Deck>();// holds the decks of flash cards

        adapter = new DeckAdapter(this, R.layout.deck_item_row,// creates a new
                                                                // custom
                                                                // adapter
                deck_data); // from the adapter class

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.deck_header_row,
                null);// Sets up the header for the
                        // list
        listView1.addHeaderView(header);// adds the header to the list view
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Intent test = new Intent(ListOfDecksActivity.this,
                        FlashCard.class);
                startActivity(test);

            }
        });
        addDeck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        addDeck.setOnClickListener(this);// sets up on click listener for submit
                                            // button

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String nameHolder;
        data.getExtras();
        nameHolder = data.getStringExtra("deckTitle");
        deck_data.add(new Deck(R.drawable.ic_launcher, nameHolder));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case (R.id.bAdd):
            Intent addDeck = new Intent(ListOfDecksActivity.this,
                    AddDeckActivity.class);

            startActivityForResult(addDeck, 1);
        }

    }

}
```

P.S. I had photos for clarity however due to a spam mechanism new users are not able to posts pictures.  If you would like to see more code or need any more detail please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: You may go ahead and edit your post to include links to the images - if you think those  will add to the clarity of your question. Someone (with more reputation) will insert these images for you in the body of your post.

Answer (score 0):

To restate the question: "What is best-practice for creating a Deck that only contains cards from a given subject?"

Using an array list is fine, if you are not planning to reuse cards across lists OR reuse cards or lists between users (e.g., make them shareable, searchable). Another consideration is that you can't keep track of much metadata if the cards are all nested within a particular Deck object. For the simplest "keep track of one users' cards" usecase, you could essentially have a flat NOSQL datamodel of decks.

However, the "best practice" in this case is probably to associate user Card objects with user Deck objects, through a SQL database with join statements, and to come up with some mechanism to sync userdata back to a central webservice. This is because most services want to make user-created cards searchable and addable for all other users.